# postgres: relation (index) does not exist when trying to alter an index

Tags: postgresql

super weird.

In an earlier migration i create an index, and I now try to remove it but I get an error that it is not found. But when I query pg_indexes it is surely there

[image]

Any ideas?  Thanks friends!!

Comment: Have you tried using [`DROP INDEX`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-dropindex.html) instead of `ALTER TABLE ... DROP CONSTRAINT`? It might complain about a constraint depending on the index, but if the constraint is indeed missing, that shouldn't be a factor.

Comment: that worked -- interesting